# If $|G|=30$ and $|Z(G)|=5$, what is the structure of $ G/Z(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question is:
If $|G|=30$ and $|Z(G)|=5$, what is the structure of $G/Z(G)$?

I don't know what do we mean by 'structure' asked in the question. Please help.

Comment: What is the behavior of the group elements under the operation? In essence, what is a common group it is isomorphic to? We know that all groups of order 6 are isomorphic to $S_3$ or $\mathbb Z / 6\mathbb Z$, and the G-Z theorem tells us what happens if $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z / 6 \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks @Nitin, for helping me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$|G|=30$, $|Z(G)|=5$. $|G/Z(G)|=6$

We know that all groups of order 6 are isomorphic to $S_3$ or $\mathbb{Z} /6\mathbb{Z}$.

well known result:
If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

If $G/Z(G) \cong \mathbb{Z} /6\mathbb{Z} $ ,then $G$ is abelian which is contradiction to $|Z(G)|=5$ . Therefore $G/Z(G) \cong S_3$

Comment: Thanks @Selva, for your quick solution. It was really helpful.